# Input 2 .wav audio files

Tags: matlab, input, wav

I need to have 2 .wav files reading and playing through a delay based function so that I can apply the effect to both signals at the same time and it seems like it should be easy, but I'm an amateur and could do with a bit of help. 
My idea was just to enhance the original signal with a slightly out of phase version but I can't seem to work it out. 
Is it possible to do this?
 So far: 
    `[Input, FS] = audioread('input_audio.wav');`

but is there someway i can put in two? I've tried with commas, spaces, semi-colans, etc such as like this...
  `[Input, FS] = audioread('Vln1_D4_open.wav':'Vln1_room_D4_open.wav');`
but this doesn't work.

the next part of the function is:

```
% First, to make sure the audio is single channel
[LEN, channels] = size(Input);
if (channels == 2) Input = Input(:,1); end;
```

so do I need to change this part instead?

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help! =)

Comment: Could you tag with the programming language you are using ? What is this code ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not 100% sure what you mean... I am using a fractal modulation script I have from uni and it works great with just one audio input.
    mod_x_y_a = fract_mod(dur_samps, peak_mod_freq, Q); % gate the     
    modulation signal
    MOD_sig = gate_modulator(mod_x_y_a);
    Modulated_Output=delay_mod(Input,FS,MOD_sig,Width);

Comment: I mean: `[Input, FS] = audioread(...)`, what is this ? Matlab? Scilab? Surely not C, C++, Java, Php,... If you want answers, you have to tag correctly, people around here commonly read only posts based upon their tags. That `input` tag is useless (unless that's a new programming language that I've never heard of...)

Comment: I have been using it in Matlab to insert audio (.wav) files into the system then I can sample the audio with 'sound' before I start to change their sampling rate, frequency, amplitude, etc. My question is simply if there is a way I can bring a second .wav file into the equation.
Thanks though.

Comment: Ok, so I told you to add the matlab tag, you didn't, so I did it for you, as I assume you want answers. Sorry, I'm not a matlab guy, can't help.